# Finding an appropriate replacement for LauncherActivityInfo

Tags: android, android-api-levels

In API level 21 LauncherActivityInfo was introduced.

I currently have to implement a program which uses the **getApplicationInfo(), getBadgedIcon(), getLabel() and getIcon()**.

I have searched on stackoverflow and on google and I cannot seem to find something suitable as a replacement. I have to support API level 19. Using this class is not possible .... Does anyone have any suggestions ?

**Link to Class**

> [LauncherActivityInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/LauncherActivityInfo.html)

Comment: take a look at `platform/packages/apps/Launcher3` source ... especially `compat` folder ...

Comment: The concept of `getBadgedIcon()` simply does not exist on earlier API levels. The rest of the information can be obtained from `PackageManager`, if you use `queryIntentActivities()` to find the `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` activities.

Comment: @Selvin I am already looking at the source code for the cyanogen launcher, CommonsWare I will check that out